# An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the > product type 'App Extension' while making a build from Command Line- xcodebuild build

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, mobile-application, xcodebuild

I have been using the following command:

```
sh "set -o pipefail && xcodebuild build CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO -UseModernBuildSystem=0 -workspace '../ProjectName.xcworkspace' -scheme 'ProjectName' | tee /Users/bamboo/Library/Logs/gym/ProjectName.log | xcpretty"
```

It only works if I select to use the Legacy build system. It gives an error for the extensions as below:

> ❌  error: An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the
> product type 'App Extension'. (in target 'WidgetExtension' from
> project 'ProjectName') error

I am using Xcode 13.1 on Big Sur. Signing is managed automatically.
It works fine with the legacy build system.

I am wondering, how reliable the solution is and what can be the alternate solution? Please share your thoughts. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The legacy build system is deprecated and could be removed in a future version of Xcode. In theory you could remove the option and and stop using the legacy build system and it should build the as Xcode would build it.

Comment: @CraigSiemens It is not building without the legacy build system setting. It gives a signing error for widget extensions in the project.  It gives below errors:
`❌  error: An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'App Extension'. (in target 'ABCWidgetExtension' from project 'ProkectName') error
 ❌  error: An empty identity is not valid when signing a binary for the product type 'App Extension'. (in target 'NotificationServiceExtension' from project 'ProjectName') error 
** BUILD FAILED **`

Comment: You would need to stop passing `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` and make sure that Xcode  project/target has a value for the `CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY` in its build settings.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @CraigSiemens  I updated my build command to

```
sh "set -o pipefail && xcodebuild build CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO - -workspace '../ProjectName.xcworkspace' -scheme 'ProjectName' | tee /Users/bamboo/Library/Logs/gym/ProjectName.log | xcpretty"
```

And it is working perfectly.